# How to show portion of country and country itself on map (child and parent)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap

I want to make a map using arcmap. I want my map look like this:

1. A complete map of a province of a country (full size)
2. In the right or left corner of the map the whole map of country should be shown and on that it should focus or highlight the province shown on map

Answer (score 2):

The functionality that you are describing is known in ArcGIS for Desktop as extent indicators which can be used for overview, locator, inset and index maps.  It is well documented in a page entitled [Using extent indicators to enhance overview or locator maps](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s900000005000000):

> Extent indicators are a way to show the extent of one data frame
>   within another data frame. This is useful when you are creating
>   overview or locator maps. ... Extent indicators are dynamic. They
>   automatically update whenever the extent of an associated data frame
>   (main map or locator map) changes.

Comment: Thanks so much from your quick reply and useful Information